# Why does Dorinda in Always and A Guy Named Joe ask "Is that your plane?"

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, dialogue, a-guy-named-joe, always

In *A guy named Joe* (1943), Dorinda (Irene Dunn) sees Pete (Spencer Tracy) in Scotland and notices his plane. She asks the question:

> **Dorinda:** Is that your plane?
>   **Pete:** The B-25 over there that looks like a ghost? Sure it's my plane. Why?
>   **Dorinda:** Nothing. Nothing.

In the Spielberg remake, *Always* (1989), it happens again (with Holly Hunter and Richard Dreyfus), but less explicitly:

> **Dorinda:** Is that your plane?
>   **Pete:** Yeah, that's my plane. C'mon, a shortcut.

Nothing more (that I can tell) is mentioned in either movie about this weird exchange, but Spielberg felt it necessary to translate this seemingly unimportant, trivial exchange to the remake.

Am I missing something? I get the allusion to a "ghost" (though only in the 1943 version), and see that the plane is spooky-looking, but is that all there is to it? Unexplained, tangential foreshadowing?